# How to delete values in a dataset after a specific date?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataset, `df1`, that looks as follows:

| Date | ID | City | State | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-03 | 10001 | Los Angeles | CA | 10 | 22 | 346 |
| 2020-03 | 10002 | Sacramento | CA | 321 | 4440 | 221 |
| ... | .... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2022-04 | 10001 | Los Angeles | CA | 133 | 1001 | 2330 |
| 2022-04 | 10002 | Sacramento | CA | 2343 | 110 | 1230 |

I want to delete all values after 2021-07. What code can I use to do so? That way, I want my range to be from `2020-03` to `2021-07`.

Note: my `date` type is `period [M]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do

```
out = df.loc[df.Date.between('2020-03','2021-07')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [string indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#periodindex-partial-string-indexing) and slice like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.arange(36)}, 
                  index = pd.period_range('2020-01', '2022-12', freq='M'))

df.loc['2020-06':'2021-01']
```

Output:

```
          A
2020-06   5
2020-07   6
2020-08   7
2020-09   8
2020-10   9
2020-11  10
2020-12  11
2021-01  12
```